# Resolving compile-time error regarding custom cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, iboutlet, outlet

I am writing an app in iOS 6.
This is a snippet of code from ViewController.m file:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = _customCell;
        _customCell = nil;

    }

    cell.firstName.textLabel = @"dsdsds";
    cell.middleName.textLabel = @"N/A";
    cell.lastName.textLabel = @"daasdsdasa";

    return cell;
}
```

These lines of code give me error (`Property 'firstName' not found on object of type 'CustomCell*'`):

```
cell.firstName.textLabel = @"dsdsds";
        cell.middleName.textLabel = @"N/A";
        cell.lastName.textLabel = @"daasdsdasa";
```

CustomeCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *middleName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lastName;

+(NSString*) reuseIdentifier;
@end

In the Outlets of CustomCell.xib:
firstName -> label
middleName -> label
lastName -> label

Referencing Outlets:
customCell -> File's Owner

Selecting the firstName label:
Referencing Outlets:
firstName -> CustomCell
firstName -> CustomCell -CustomCellIdentifier

Selecting the middleName label:
lastName -> Custom Cell - CustomCellIdentifier
middleName -> Custom Cell

Selecting the lastName label:
lastName -> Custom Cell
middleName -> Custom Cell- Custom Cell Identifier
```

So, what is the prob? In my opinion it has something to do with Outlets.

Comment: Did you synthesize these properties in .m class

Comment: If iOS6 you don't need to synthesize properties

Comment: In fact I cannot synthesize them in hat file cause first of all it must be declared at .h file. Although now it is in different file

Comment: What's the File's owner class and is the `customCell` property of that class a CustomCell or a UITableViewCell ?

Comment: Did you `#import "CustomCell.h"`?

Comment: There are two .xib's files. Regarding CustomCell.xib in the compartment of 'Referencing Outlets' customCell -> File's Owner. Yes, customCell is a property: 
@property(assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomCell *customCell; has been held at VieController.h

Comment: xib's and outlets have nothing to do with this error.  It may not work as you want it to because of them, but they do not cause this error....

Comment: Are these errors at compile time or run-time?

Comment: It is an error which occurs before performing compilation

Answer (score 1):

The error `(Property 'firstName' not found on object of type 'CustomCell*'):` means that the compiler does not know about a property by the name of `firstName`.  You need to inform the compiler what properties are available within a class, typically by importing the header file.

So, at the top of the file where your table view code is, put:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"
```

(Note that it goes before your `@implementation` block, up with the other `#import`'s.

Comment: It has been imported. No affect as you may see.

Comment: Really?  At the top of ViewController.m?  Is that the only error that you are getting?

Comment: Ooops, there are two more errors regarding middle and last name

Comment: Can you copy and paste your entire ViewController.m into your question?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a couple of mistakes in your code:

```
cell.firstName.textLabel = @"dsdsds";
cell.middleName.textLabel = @"N/A";
cell.lastName.textLabel = @"daasdsdasa";
```

The issue is there is no property like textLabel for UILabel.

Change it to:

```
cell.firstName.text  = @"dsdsds";
cell.middleName.text = @"N/A";
cell.lastName.text   = @"daasdsdasa";
```

If you not synthesized the property use the following instead:

```
cell._firstName.text  = @"dsdsds";
cell._middleName.text = @"N/A";
cell._lastName.text   = @"daasdsdasa";
```

Also change:

```
if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
}
```

to

```
if (cell == nil) {
         NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: According to XCODE text has been deprecated, I shall use textLabel. The resy fix is not helping either.

Comment: @uml: that is for cell. Cell.text is deprecated so you need to use cell.textLabel. There is no property like textLabel for UILabel

Comment: @uml: that was a typo. please check it

Comment: Nope. Same errors. I followed your suggestion regarding naming and so on

Comment: @uml: did you changed to _firstName ?

Comment: He is using iOS 6.0 which has auto-synthesis, therefore he has setters and getters....

Comment: @Inafiziger: in iOS 6 if you not synthesized your property iOS will wutomatically synthesize that in the form of `_yourIvar`

Comment: Yes, and therefore he shouldn't be using cell._firstName.  He should use cell.firstName as he is...  Plus in your answer you say "If you not synthesized the property".  (ergo my previous comment)

Comment: auto-synthesize is a function of the compiler, not the OS.  Newer XCode is just injecting that code for us.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, but if he is targeting iOS 6 then his compiler supports auto-synthesis...

Answer (score 0):

why do you have the class method `+reuseIdentifier` in your .h file?  The `UITableViewCell` class that you inherit from has a property with that name, so that's a tad confusing.

Also, the convention is to use "weak" for your outlets: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *firstName;` because the view will have a strong copy of it's subviews.

I'm not sure why your property isn't being found.  It's a runtime error.  If things were not wired up in the nib correctly; you'd get an exception as soon as you try to instantiate the that view.  Did you set the "class" of that view to CustomCell?  (Though if you didn't you should be dequeuing a regular TableViewCell and wouldn't have been able to set your outlets, so...) Hmm.

Comment: Weak is not allowed in ARC and GC. An error received once switching to weak and performing synthesizing. The class for .xib has been set to CustomCell

Comment: There's no GC for iOS; and strong/weak are specifically for ARC.  If you're targeting older iOS; you can sometimes use unsafe_unretained in lieu of weak.  Anyway, good luck with your issue.